# Windows shortcut for display layout

Tags: windows, windows-10, multiple-monitors, resolution

When we want to change a keyboard Layout, Windows lets us choose a keyboard shortcut to make this simple, but is there a way to make a shortcut for switching display layouts, such as these in the image?

- **One monitor on with 4K resolution, two monitors disabled**

[image: One monitor on with 4K resolution, two monitors disabled]

- **Monitor #3 on the left with 1366x768 resolution, the other two with 1080p, with #2 in the middle**

[image: Monitor on the left with 1366x768 resolution, the other two with 1080p]

- **Monitor #3 with 1366x768, Monitor #2 in the middle with 4K, and #1 on the right with 1080p, all of them horizontally aligned**

[image: Monitor #3 with 1366x768, Monitor #2 in the middle with 4K, and #1 on the right with 1080p]

Comment: I do know that there is software that will do this for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be doable with [Display Changer](http://12noon.com/?page_id=80)

For your keyboard shortcut:

```
-create a batch with your dccmd.exe command 
-create a shortcut of the batch 
-set a keyboard shortcut in the properties
```

Comment: How do you create that batch? I used `dccmd.exe -create="name.xml"` and on loading, it gives me [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0eaw.png) as seen here: https://superuser.com/q/1697844/910769