# Programatticaly control the screen layout in Windows (10)

Tags: windows, windows-10, display, multiple-monitors

In Linux, it is easy to change the display settings with e.g. [XRandR](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Xrandr). This works for as many displays as you can connect. Specifically, I would like to activate/enable and move the layout of multiple displays.
Easy example (I think it is self-explainatory):

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --right-of HDMI2
```

---

My goal here is more specifically, to switch between two Layouts. The tool must be able to take care not only of the actively used displays, but also the disconncted ones beyond the third monitor. Layout 1 looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of Layout 1]

and Layout 2:

[image: Screenshot of Layout 2]

My long search for a port of XRandR or a similar software for Windows didn't yield a good result. Especially the support for **more than two or three** displays is subpar.

- The Windows-tool [`displayswitch`](https://superuser.com/a/1116541/910769) exists, but it only makes sense for at most two displays. You can just select [`\internal` or `\extend`](https://superuser.com/a/1116541/910769), but not `\extend \monitor=4` or something like that. There also is `dpiscaling`, but it doesn't provide a good cmd-interface.
- [Nir's MultiMonitorTool](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/multi_monitor_tool.html) [from this answer](https://superuser.com/a/774306/910769) does manage the layout in some sense, but only connects one display at a time of the first three, NOT correctly Display 4 or 5. (The [TVGameLauncher](https://sourceforge.net/projects/tvgamelauncher/) is not what I need. I also tried the other tools in NirCmd.)
- There is the [(12noon) Display Changer](https://12noon.com/?page_id=641) [(guide on how to use)](https://elbruno.com/2020/05/08/tools-display-changer-ii-change-your-monitor-configuration-with-1-click/), which seems to fit, but it is again only able to connect the first three displays. Trying to not specify the monitors by hand, but to use use `-create` (save) and then `-congigure` (reload) just gives me [this errror](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0eaw.png) for all versions.
  The output for `dc64cmd -listmonitors` is lacking the disconnected displays - it only works fine for up to three displays:

```
Monitor: Generic PnP Monitor
Device: \\.\DISPLAY1
Adapter: Intel(R) UHD Graphics
(1920 x 1080 x 32 bpp) 60Hz default up, attached, primary (0,0)

Monitor: Generic PnP Monitor
Device: \\.\DISPLAY2
Adapter: Intel(R) UHD Graphics
(1920 x 1200 x 32 bpp) 59Hz default up, attached (1920,-109)

Monitor:
Device: \\.\DISPLAY3
Adapter: Intel(R) UHD Graphics
(1920 x 1200 x 32 bpp) 59Hz default up, attached (3840,-109)
```

I should note, that my graphics card is able to support 3 displays only at the same time. So to switch from Layout 1 to Layout 2, I would

- disconnect/detach 2
- disconnect/detach 3
- connect/attach 4
- connect/attach 5

---

Preferrably the tool should not need admin privileges. I don't know if the new Windows 10 settings changed something in comparison to older versions, but I expect third-party software to be compatible.

Ultimately, I would like to use it in AutoHotkey, but this is secondary.

Note: I didn't discuss the tools for a single display, but just to name a few: [QRes](https://sourceforge.net/projects/qres/), [nircmd.exe setdisplay](https://superuser.com/a/89360/910769) or [ChangeScreenResolution.exe](https://superuser.com/a/1047172/910769)

Comment: This is not a duplicate to [this referenced question](https://superuser.com/questions/394601/change-display-arrangement-via-batch-command-line-on-windows-7). The latter one just asks for extend/clone/single display x. 
None of the answers applies for more than 2 or 3 displays, I edited my question for clarification.

Comment: Don't the SaveConfig/LoadConfig commands of MultiMonitorTool help in your case?

Comment: I am able to adjust 5 monitors with (12noon) Display Changer 2.
Maybe you were using Display Changer 1 and may not have support for more than 3?